# Load JavaScript file common for all HTML files

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-tabhost

I am creating `android application using Tabhost` and having the following

```
1. App having 4 tabs
2. Each tab in Tabhost having WebViews. 
3. Loaded local HTML files with these WebViews.  
4. 4 Local HTML files having more than 8 js files. 
5. but 8 js files are same for all HTML files
```

**Issue:** i can load 8 js files separately in each HTML files. This affects performance

**Expected:** We can load `all java script files in Layout.cshtml file when we using ASP.NET MVC pages`. Like that i want to `load all js files common for all local HTML files`.

Please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this will not be possible because the `WebView`s are independent containers running separate WebKit engine in each instance.

One possibility in your case would be to emulate the `TabHost` user interface with a single `WebView`. To be specific, you would have to create the tabs using web content itself, so that you make use of a single `WebView`, which contains HTML for the 4 different tabs in it.